# How to setup logstash on Azure with windows configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, elasticsearch, logstash

I've managed to get logstash working as a Proof Of Concept, locally on my windows setup. Here's an overview of the setup:

- My .Net App writes messages to a logger.txt file, through NLogger.
- I have logstash running as a windows service after following this guide (https://community.ulyaoth.net/threads/how-to-install-logstash-on-a-windows-server-with-kibana-in-iis.17/)
- The logstash agent takes the .txt file as an 'input', filters the info into more meaningful fields then  writes these to my ElastcSearch instance.
- I can then view these with the Kibana Web UI to get some meaningful info from my logs.
- Happy days (works on my machine!)

My problem arrives when trying to move this onto my production environment on windows Azure.

All the info on the web currently mentions running Linux VMs to host logstash on Azure but being a M$ monkey, I'd rather not.

So any guides/advice on getting the logstash agent running on Azure in a fail-safe/ automated manner is much appreciated?

Comment: I´m searching for the same thing, my intention was [this](https://github.com/urielha/log4stash) here.

Comment: Are you trying to run a Worker/Webrole on Azure or do you want to use your own VM. In case you run your own VM you can set one up manually installing logstash and create a general image as baseline and use that image to spin of your actual vm.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a PowerShell script available that is able to setup ELK in Azure. See https://github.com/mspnp/semantic-logging/tree/elk.